# Borel-Cantelli lemma implications

Tags: probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

My previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4437604/increment-property-of-brownian-motion/4437985#4437985) here on stack exchange has caused a follow-up question.

The Borel-Cantelli lemma tells us that, if for any $\varepsilon > 0$ we have

> $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(\vert X_n - X \vert > \varepsilon) < \infty$, then $X_n \to X$ a.s.

Especially, if I can show that

> $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{\vert X_n\vert}{n} > \varepsilon\right) < \infty$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$, then $X_n/n \to 0$ a.s.

But, if I can only show that

> $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{\vert X_n\vert}{n} > \varepsilon\right) < \infty$ holds for a fixed $\varepsilon > 0$,

then I can only conclude that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \vert X_n \vert/n \leq \varepsilon$ a.s. Hence I still know, that the sequence $\vert X_n \vert/n$ is converging almost surely, but  I lose information about the exact value of the limit, is that true?

Comment: What if $X_n=(-1)^n n$? Then let $\eps=2$.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So I know even less, I can only conclude that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \vert X_n \vert /N \leq \varepsilon$, right?

Comment: Yes, since if the limsup is not bounded by $\epsilon$, then $|X_n|/n > \epsilon$ infinitely often, which contradicts Borel-Cantelli

Answer (score 1):

Indeed,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{\vert X_n\vert}{n} > \varepsilon\right) < \infty$$
only for some fixed $\varepsilon$ only implies that
$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\lvert X_n\rvert/n\leqslant\varepsilon$.
The example by Steven Mai, namely, $X_n=(-1)^n n$ and $\varepsilon=2$ shows that we cannot deduce that $X_n/n\to 0$ almost surely.